# How can I access a value in my struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, std, stdvector

I have a struct, vector and private variable as below:

```
typedef struct _ItemData
{
    col colour;         
    int xposition;              
} ItemData;

typedef std::vector<ItemData> Data;

Data *lookupTable;
```

I intialize the table using:

```
lookupTable = NULL;
```

When I add to ItemData, I do so using:

```
ItemData newData = { colour, x };
lookupTable[y].push_back(newData);
```

This adds the colour and x co-ordinate to the Y line.

I am trying to access the colour and x variable later on using:

```
lookupTable[yCounter][xCounter].colour
lookupTable[yCounter][xCounter].xposition
```

but it seems to be having no good result, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: What is `lookupTable` a pointer?  Also the typedef for `struct`s is a C-ism and is not needed in C++.  You ccan just use the struct name instead of `struct struct_name` in C++.

Comment: I've been given the code and instructed not to change it, other than when grabbing x and colour, I'm unsure whether it's a pointer, but if so, how would I grab them using pointers?

Comment: You are using the lookupTable pointer as an array without having allocated any memory for it.  Use another `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Peter, how would I do this?

Comment: @GilfoyMayhew `std::vector<Data> lookupTable`

Comment: What does *"it seems to be having no good result"* even mean?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am not getting the x and colour back i am receiving random numbers

Answer (score 0):

first - no need to typedef struct (or class) in c++.

```
struct ItemData
{
    col colour;         
    int xposition;              
};
```

Then you need

```
typedef std::vector<ItemData> Data;

Data lookupTable;


ItemData newData = { colour, x };
lookupTable.push_back(newData);
```

maybe you wanted an array / collection / vector of vectors, not clear. So I just assumed you wanted the simplest possible thing

to get the data back do

```
col colour = lookupTable[0].colour;
```

Comment: How do I then get the x and colour values from this?

Comment: Sorry, being more clear, I need to be able to access each element where Y is a number, hence: lookupTable[y].push_back(newData);

Comment: why not read the docs on how to use std::vector or std::array. If after that you still ahve problems that ask another question. But, push_back says 'add this at the end', [Y] do this to element Y , you cant combine the 2

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm